# Почему метод insert в python'e выводит числа не по порядку, а наоборот?

Tags: python, массивы, list

Задача: **Дан одномерный массив числовых значений, насчитывающий N элементов. Вставить группу из М новых элементов, начиная с позиции К.**
Выводит числа из insert наоборот, а не то, как они введены по порядку. Можно ли обойтись без срезов или стоит их применить?

```py
a = []
n = int(input('Введите число: '))
for i in range(n):
    d = int(input())
    a.append(d)
h = int(input('Введите число -'))
k = int(input('Введите диапазон -'))
for j in range(h):
    s = int(input())
    a.insert(k,s)
print(a)
```

Входные данные:

```
Введите число - 4
1
2
3
4
Введите число - 2
Введите диапазон - 1
56
32
```

Вывод:

```py
[1, 32, 56, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Вы же вставляете в одну и ту же позицию, поэтому ранние сдвигаются в конец. Можно, например, увеличивать k+=1

Comment: Потому что вы вставляете элементы в одно и то же место. Поэтому в результирующем массиве они идут в обратном порядке.

Comment: А как можно это исправить?  @DmitryK

Comment: Как написал MBo - увеличивать `k` на единицу после каждой вставки - `a.insert(k,s) k=k+1`. Либо срезами - делаете ввод в отдельный массив `b`, а потом - `a[ : k ] + b + a[ k : ]`

Answer (score 0):

Как написал MBo - увеличивать k на единицу после каждой вставки

```
for j in range(h):
    s = int(input())
    a.insert(k,s)
    k+=1
```

Либо срезами - делаете ввод в отдельный массив b, а потом - a[ : k ] + b + a[ k : ]

```
for j in range(h):
    b.append(int(input()))
c = a[ : k ] + b + a[ k : ]
```

Срезы применять имеет смысл:

- в общем случае работает быстрее, чем вставка по 1 элементу
- синтаксически понятнее, даже визуально видно что делаете - берете массив a с начала до k-го элемента, потом массив b, потом остаток массива а от к-того элемента до конца.